# extract file full path using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on photo uploader.I have a requirement like when user select photo from Desktop. I need to show photo and name both before he will start click on upload.The reason being showing the photo at client side is because he can verify by seeing photo at first.

so my problem is I m not getting the path. when i m using

```
<input type='file' />
```

I can see the path.but unable to get path from it at client side.

Any suggestion???

Answer (score 1):

For security reasons you cannot do this using javascript as you don't have access to the user file system.

Comment: thats fine...i am asking is there any way to do this...?

Comment: You could use Flash, Java Applet, Silverlight but the user will need to approve and install it.

Comment: No, flash, java or silverlight or possibly a plugin for the browser can do it, but there is no JavaScript/jQuery way to do it.